# Как правильно передать данные

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Под моим [предыдущим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1198698/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-then?noredirect=1#comment2091707_1198698) [vsemozhebuty](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/321883/vsemozhebuty) посоветовал мне описать проблему, касательно глобальной переменной.

При отправлении страницы с сервера, мне также нужно отправить курсы валют.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        rates: rates // курсы валют
    });
});
```

```html
<%= rates %>
```

Делаю я это в отдельном модуле:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

fetch('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        module.exports = res;
    });
```

И подключаю в главный файл:

```js
const rates = require('./modules/exchange_rates');
```

Получается глобальная переменная. Как можно более правильно решить данную задачу: при запуске сервера получить json курсов валют и передавать это на страницу при загрузке?

Comment: Зачем для этого глобальная переменная, если можно просто await'ить функцию, возвращающую курсы валют? https://pastebin.com/VVdXpm6P

Comment: Более продвинутый вариант с кэшированием курсов на один час https://pastebin.com/j380379x

Comment: @andreymal напиши ответ!

Comment: @nörbörnën я ещё не уверен, что это ответ... а ещё не уверен, что в node.js и express так вообще принято писать)

Comment: @andreymal нормально написано. и нормально запускается https://repl.it/@norbornen/QuarterlyVaguePhysics#index.js